# Which query is more performant using groupBy in subquery?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization

I have next task:
I have table **columns** and I have table **tasks** - One Column **has** Many Tasks, Task **belongsTo** one Column.

First query^

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       color,
       created_at,
       CASE
           WHEN jt.tc IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE jt.tc
       END
FROM columns AS c1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS tc,
          column_id
   FROM tasks AS t
   GROUP BY column_id) AS jt ON c1.id=jt.column_id
WHERE board_id = 'some id here';
```

In that case in **jt** table will be grouped all records from tasks table and with big amount of data in tasks it will not work at all (very slow slow speed)

Second query:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       color,
       created_at,
       CASE
           WHEN jt.tc IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE jt.tc
       END
FROM columns AS c1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS tc,
          column_id
   FROM tasks AS t
   LEFT JOIN columns c ON t.column_id = c.id
   WHERE c.board_id = 'some id here'
   GROUP BY column_id) AS jt ON c1.id=jt.column_id
WHERE board_id = 'some id here';
```

In that case within **jt** table will be only those columns which i need, so where clause will cut selection a lot.

Am i right?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The standard answer of "it depends" applies here. You've given hypotheticals without the details of indexes, table sizes, database platform and version. All of those things influence whether queries run faster when rewritten certain ways. Run explain plans on the queries. That will show you what the database optimizer thinks and give you a quantifiable comparison.